# BeautifulSoup: scraping spanish characters issue

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm trying to get some Spanish text from a website using BeautifulSoup and urllib2. I currently get this: `Â¡Hola! Â¿CÃ³mo estÃ¡s?`.
I have tried applying the different unicode functions I have seen on related threads, but nothing seems to work for my issue:

```
# import the main window object (mw) from aqt
from aqt import mw
# import the "show info" tool from utils.py
from aqt.utils import showInfo
# import all of the Qt GUI library
from aqt.qt import *

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2



wiki = "http://spanishdict.com/translate/hola"

page = urllib2.urlopen(wiki)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

dictionarydiv = soup.find("div", { "class" : "dictionary-neodict-example" })

dictionaryspans = dictionarydiv.contents

firstspan = dictionaryspans[0]

firstspantext = firstspan.contents

thetext = firstspantext[0]

thetextstring = str(thetext)
```

Comment: `print thetextstring` looks just fine

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo only if on a UTF-8 terminal.  The OP is likely on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

`thetext` is type `<class 'BeautifulSoup.NavigableString'>`.  Printing it returns a Unicode string, which will be encoded in the output terminal encoding:

```
print thetext
```

Output (in a Windows console):

```
¡Hola! ¿Cómo estás?
```

This will work on any terminal configured for an encoding supporting the Unicode characters being printed.

You'll get `UnicodeEncodeError` if your terminal is configured with an encoding that doesn't support the Unicode characters you try to print.

Using `str` on that type returns a byte string...in this case encoded in UTF-8.  If you print that on anything but a UTF-8-configured terminal, you'll get an incorrect display.